# How can I disable (grey out) a Checkbutton in Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

I can't figure out how to grey out a Tkinter `Checkbutton`.

I tried using `state=DISABLED` but it didn't work and I got an error saying

> _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-enable": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

How can I temporarily disable a `Checkbutton`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `state=DISABLED` is the correct way to do this.

However, you must be putting it in the wrong place.  `state` is an option of `Checkbutton`, so it needs to be used like this:

```
Checkbutton(state=DISABLED)
```

Below is a sample script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, DISABLED
root = Tk()
check = Checkbutton(text="Click Me", state=DISABLED)
check.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to change a checkbutton's state programmatically, use [`Tkinter.Checkbutton.config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method).

Below is a sample script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, DISABLED
root = Tk()
def click():
    check.config(state=DISABLED)
check = Checkbutton(text="Click Me", command=click)
check.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah I rewrote it and it worked. Must've done something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that activating a widget back is **not**, contrary to an intuition one might have, with `state=ENABLED`. It's actually `state=NORMAL`...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Checkbutton.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

This solution worked for me.