# How can you disable a button mid-program in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Let's say I have a button, `button = Button(root, text="Hello", command = somecommand)` and I want to disable it if some condition is true mid-program. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def hi():
    print("hi")
button=Button(root,text="Say hello",command=hi)
button.pack()
while 1:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    if 1==1:
        #disable button here
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any research on this? The ability to modify the attributes of a widget are well documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Checkbutton Tkinter (grey out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687220/disable-checkbutton-tkinter-grey-out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmark this [reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) (not perfect, but extremely helpful).  The [Button page](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) says "state: Set this option to tk.DISABLED to gray out the button and make it unresponsive. Has the value tk.ACTIVE when the mouse is over it. Default is tk.NORMAL. ".  In other words, `button['state'] = DISABLED` and `button['state'] = NORMAL` will de-activate and restore `button`.